listen tcp: lookup localhost: no such host` - Exit Status 1 in Go Application
I am encountering the following error when trying to run my Go application:
2024/10/28 12:59:30 listen tcp: lookup localhost: no such host
exit status 1

Context:

My Go application is designed to connect to a MySQL database and start a web server.
I am using the go-sql-driver/mysql package for database connections.
My connection string is as follows:
dbURL := "root:mypassword@tcp(127.0.0.1:3306:3306)/simplerest?charset=utf8&parseTime=True&loc=Local"



Troubleshooting Steps Taken:

Connection String Update: I tried using 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost in the connection string:
dbURL := "root:mypassword@tcp(127.0.0.1:3306)/simplerest?charset=utf8&parseTime=True&loc=Local"


Hosts File: Verified that localhost maps to 127.0.0.1 in my system's hosts file.
MySQL Server Status: Confirmed that the MySQL server is running on port 3306.

Environment:

Go Version: 1.23.2 windows/amd64

Question:
Despite taking these steps, I still receive the same error when I attempt to run the application. Can anyone provide insights on why this might be happening and how I can resolve the issue?

Can you please try to provide a minimal, reproducible example (even if it's only reproducable on your computer). There have been issues raised that include this error (eg 1, eg 2) but without seeing your code it's difficult to know if they are relevant (your second connection string resolved the port double up included in the first, but neither reference localhost).

Try check the table: mysql.user.
Set the host to '%'.
mysql> update user set host = '%' where user = 'root';

mysql> flush privileges;


If you want to connect to the mysql using absolute ip, you should modify the config file.
#The config file is the following path for me.

/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf 

bind-address            = 0.0.0.0 
mysqlx-bind-address     = 0.0.0.0

or 

bind-address            = *
mysqlx-bind-address     = *


Which is 127.0.0.1 as default.
Restart mysql and it will works.
